# Eloquent - Detect multiple column duplicate data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-collection

I have a table that has 3 column `id, sub_id, name`. That is a pretty big table and there are some duplicates.

What is the best way to detect the duplicates so that I can remove them?

I tried this but it returns everything (I guess thinking ids are making them non-unique)

```
$collection = \App\MyModel::all();
$colUnique = $collection->unique(['name', 'sub_id']);
$dupes = $collection->diff($colUnique);
```

I want to get the models that has same `name` and `sub_id`.

```
id    sub_id   name
1       2      John
2       2      John   <- duplicate
3       2      Robin  <- unique
```

Comment: why dont you use toArray() function and get all the duplicate entries by running  php functions array_unique and array_diff , Then run a foreach loop and delete them.

Comment: Or if you want to go SQL way use groupBy function while retrieving model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize [`Collection.groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby) method.

```php
$collection = \App\MyModel::all();

$collection
  // Group models by sub_id and name
  ->groupBy(function ($item) { return $item->sub_id.'_'.$item->name; })
  // Filter to remove non-duplicates
  ->filter(function ($arr) { return $arr->count()>1; })
  // Process duplicates groups
  ->each(function ($arr) {
    $arr
      // Sort by id  (so first item will be original)
      ->sortBy('id')
      // Remove first (original) item from dupes collection
      ->splice(1)
      // Remove duplicated models from DB
      ->each(function ($model) {
        $model->delete();
      });
  })
```

Comment: From a performance point of view, calling `\App\MyModel::all();` and getting all the models in memory is really a bad thing to do...

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin That depends.

Answer (score 5):

My best bet would be DB::Query.

**Step 1: Fetch data by group by**

```
$uniqueData = DB::table('TABLE_NAME')
                  ->groupBy(['sub_id', 'name'])
                  ->select('id')
                  ->toArray();
```

**Step 2: Delete duplicate record.**

```
$noOfDeletedRecords = DB::table('TABLE_NAME')
                          ->whereNotIn($uniqueData)
                          ->delete();
```

**Benefits:**
1. Only 2 Queries
2. Better performance over collection.

Comment: While this method is more efficient, it could raise issues if model has delete observer/handler. Also, you should select `MIN(id)`.

Comment: A slight changes needed , but +1 for better performance. Performance is the key.

Comment: @Styx Yes, I agree with you. In case of Observer/Handler this approach is problematic. There is a work around, instead of DB use Model directly. i.e. ` `MyModel::whereNotIn($ARRAY)->delete()` . Problem solved. :D

Comment: @RutvijKothari I was just referring to Styx reply. I like your way.. No worries.